# issue with merging or appending into one dataframe from many dataframes in global environment

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, dplyr

I have many dataframes in my global environment in R.

These are like (not in sequential numbers):

```
df1, df2, df4, df7, df8, df10, df15....
```

I want to merge these into one (because all of these DFs have same column names, total 6 of these).

what I did:

```
 lst <- as.data.frame(unlist(list(ls())))
 names(lst) <- "List"
 lst$List
```

Which returns me something like:

```
 lst$List
 [1] df1  df10 df11 df13 df14 df15 df16 df17 df18 df2  df20 df21 df23 df24 df25 df3  df4  df5  df6  df7  df8  df9
```

but when I tried to merge all these columns using the below code, it did not do what I expectec (I expected rows to get appended into one Large Single DF):

```
DF <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), lst$List)
```

Comment: See `rbind` to combine data frames by row

Comment: `do.call(rbind,mget(ls(pattern = "df")))` in base R or `dplyr::bind_rows(mget(ls(pattern = "df")))` or `data.table::rbindlist(mget(ls(pattern = "df")))`

Comment: or even `Reduce(rbind,mget(ls(pattern = "df")))` although this will be slower as compared to `do.call` since this does the row-binding iteratively

Comment: *It did not do what I expected* ... and what did you expect? If columns are all the same, you want to append not merge. BTW consider using a list to hold many similar-structured dfs and not have to track all down with environment scanners. like `ls`, `mget`, `eapply`.

Comment: @Onyambu Thanks and problem solved.

Comment: did you need it as an answer?

Comment: yes i think this is the one